# The blog post announcing the Student Ambassador program is missing a space in "StackOverflow"

Tags: bug, status-completed, blog, wording

In the recent blog post [Stack Overflow is launching a Student Ambassador program. Here’s how to apply.](https://stackoverflow.blog/2022/08/29/stack-overflow-student-ambassador-program-how-to-apply/), under the section "**Why are we launching this program?**", the "Stack Overflow" is displayed without spaces.

In plain text from the blog post:

> We want to learn how you engage with our site, get your input on what we can improve, and work out how to evolve StackOverflow as a learning tool for the next generation of technologists. We will also offer the opportunity to pursue interesting challenges and earn rewards.

As per the [Trademark Guidance](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/trademark-guidance) under the section "**Proper Use of the Stack Exchange Name**" it denotes:

> **Stack Overflow** is a programmer Q&A site on the Stack Exchange Network. As a name, Stack Overflow, is always written "Stack Overflow" (two words, capital letters).

So in the blog post, it should be corrected as "Stack Overflow" instead "StackOverflow".

**Screenshot for reference:**

[image: Stack Overflow without space]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thanks for the heads-up! The blog post has now been updated to give Stack Overflow the space it needs:

> We want to learn how you engage with our site, get your input on what we can improve, and work out how to evolve **Stack Overflow** as a learning tool for the next generation of technologists.

Comment: I thought at first you follow Yaakov way, but it's actually just a quote from the blog. :D